# Unable to hold on an element on mouse hover

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, hover, selenium-chromedriver, mousehover

There is a mouse hover drop-down where the drop-down appears on hover and disappears if the mouse pointer is moved way from the drop-down. I tried using **"Actions"** class to hover on the drop-down element but i cannot see the drop-down after the mouse hover is performed. The drop-down doesn't stay till the next action is performed.

Is there any way where there is a wait after the hover is performed so that the drop-down appears for a longer time in order to select/click elements from the drop-down?

**Code:**

```
driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='main']/div[3]/button")‌​);
Actions action= new Actions(driver); 
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

**Environment:**

```
Chrome version: 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
Chrome driver: 2.27
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more info as below: 1. Can you show the code you have tried? 2. Provide the HTML DOM. 3. Screenshot of the element.

Comment: I have used to below mentioned code:
    driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement element =       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='main']/div[3]/button"));
    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same code that you wrote for mouse hover action and try following solution before mouse hover action.

- Keep mouse cursor on task bar.

  OR
- Move mouse cursor at (0, 0) browser location.

Comment: setting the cursor position(0,0) before hover worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After perform() you need to traverse through the elements.

Here is the working code:

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class MouseHoverDemo_w3school {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='dropdown dropdown2']/button"));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(ele).perform();
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='dropdown-content']/a"));
        int total_count = links.size();
        for (int i=0; i<total_count; i++)
        {
            WebElement element = links.get(i);
            String text = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            System.out.println("Link Name is : "+text);

        }

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Let me know if this answers your question.